# NoSuchMethodError in crawler4j CrawelController class

Tags: java, berkeley-db-je, crawler4j

I am using example given [here](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/basic/) And included necessary files(crawler4j-3.3.zip &crawler4j-3.x-dependencies.zip) from [here] (http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/downloads/list) in my build path and run path.

I am getting this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentConfig.setAllowCreate(Z)Lcom/sleepycat/je/EnvironmentConfig;
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController.<init>(CrawlController.java:90)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.examples.basic.BasicCrawlController.main(BasicCrawlController.java:100)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`
.

I am not able to understand the reason of error as there is required function in [this file](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/CrawlController.java?r=9bc8c1b54eedfd8fd0384822517159d997670e5e), see line number 75.

Please help me out . I dont have much expertise in Java . Is this problem is related to [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBCACHE-1611). If yes, how to fix it.

Comment: Your image doesn't show the full exception. So please put the textual copy of the exception. A quick thought, is  your version of crawler4j might not have the method you are trying to access or you may not have the methods defined with the signature you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The problem is very similar to [JBCACHE-1611](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBCACHE-1611). It is version incompatibility with [Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/index-098622.html).

Just check that you have the latest version of [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/downloads/list) with proper dependencies (`crawler4j-3.3.zip` and `crawler4j-3.x-dependencies.zip`).
This should reveal the problem.

If it doesn't, try building crawler4j from source with dependency on je-4.0.92.jar.

Comment: You might also accidentally have an older version of BDB on the classpath as well as the correct one, which would cause a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a issue related with revision between libs, you can try this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadje4092jar.htm to find a higher version