# Crawler4j - Getting exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: crawler4j

I am trying to setup crawler4j via eclipse(juno).
When I run it, I am getting the below exception(even though the program keeps running without  logging anything):

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentConfig.setAllowCreate(Z)Lcom/sleepycat/je/EnvironmentConfig;
>   at
>   edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController.(CrawlController.java:90)
>   at
>   packCrawler.BasicCrawlController.main(BasicCrawlController.java:81)"
>   error?. I am also getting the same error. When I clicked on
>   (CrawlController.java:90)"

I could see that there is no source attached for CrawlController in crawler4j-3.4.jar. So I can't make out whether there is method "`setAllowCreate`" or not.

There is similar post at : [NoSuchMethodError in crawler4j CrawelController class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160206/nosuchmethoderror-in-crawler4j-crawelcontroller-class/13542984#13542984)

But it does not exactly say how the problem got fixed. Does anybody have any suggestion?

Thanks very much for your time.
Neha

Comment: Also,I have added the jar crawler4j-3.0-sources having CrawlController.java with setAllowCreate method. But still getting the error.

Comment: It got solved, surely it was some version error. I can not pin point exactly but I created afresh the crawler4j project using crawler4j-3.3.zip and crawler4j-3.x-dependencies.zip.I built the project, added my source folder with 2 classes which I wanted to run and that is all.

Comment: hi, if you find my answer ok, may I ask you to accept it please ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the new crawler4j github: https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j

Use the maven dependency system and all of your trouble will be gone!:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.uci.ics</groupId>
    <artifactId>crawler4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You will get the latest version (now on github instead of google code)

Using an Dependency Management Tool such as Maven, you will automatically escape all classpath hell...